# What is the syntax of using placement new in constructor initialize list

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Suppose I have a class

```
class MyClass
int buf[10];
public:
MyClass(int i) {
    new (&buf) OtherClass(i); // How to move this to constructor initialize list?
}
```

Simply copy that line to the place after `:` not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would use the constructed object; I suppose `MyClass` has a data member pointer to the object, then initialize the pointer like:

```
class MyClass {
int buf[10];
OtherClass* p;
public:
    MyClass(int i) : p(new (&buf) OtherClass(i)) {  
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without the `OtherClass*p` member. I mean if `buf` is a union with a `OtherClass`  member. `p` will have the the same value as &buf, making it unneeded right?

Comment: @J.Doe AFAIK it's not possible; member intializer list is used for initializing members..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refinement of [@songyunayao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43882338/11107541), replete with the removal of `*p`:

```
template <class T2, class ...TArgs>
inline static monostate construct_helper(void* placement, TArgs&&...args)
{
    new (placement) T2(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    return {};
}

class MyClass {
    union {
        std::byte buf[40];
        std::monostate dummy;
    };
public:
    MyClass(int i) : dummy(
        construct_helper<OtherClass>(buf, i)) {}
};
```

It's not the prettiest, but not so bad all things considered.